# WPF recommended way of switching style for button

Tags: c#, wpf

Basically I have two buttons side by side and I've defined two set of styles. For illustration purpose, says `styleA` is white and `styleB` is black. The idea should be somewhat simple, when user click `buttonA`, it will be applying `styleA` which is white in color and `buttonB` will apply `styleB` and turn into black vice versa. However after hours of researching, there is no simple way of achieving this? Some suggesting using `RelativeSource AncestorType` while some using `Converter`. Am I totally off from track as I believe my objective should be able to accomplish easily. Please help as I'm very new to WPF area

Comment: The logic is unclear, can you rephrase it ?

Comment: @NicolasRepiquet: Its simple, there are two buttons by default applying `styleB` and hence both are black in color. Now says `buttonA` gets clicked, it will apply `styleB` and turn into white while `buttonB` remain black. Then, when user click on `buttonB`, `buttonB` will apply `styleB` while `buttonA` apply `styleA` and as result, `buttonB` will be in white while `buttonA` is in black

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `ToggleButton` may suit your more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is have your two styles defined in a resource dictionary, and then in your click handlers for the button or Selected for the radio button, dynamically find the resource in question, and apply that found resource (style) to the element you want to re-style.

Comment: Yes I think the direction is correct. Can you please provide some simple code on how to find the resource from event handler and apply the found resource to the element?

Comment: Take a look here.  This will put you in the right direction. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.findresource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.  You then cast the found resource as as Style.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the most simple way to do this is to use RadioButtons with styleA and a trigger that if it's checked it will get styleB. By that you get "for free" that when you click one of the buttons, it gets styleB and the other button returns to styleA.

Comment: Oh god finally someone understand what I want. YES the behaviour is like a radio button but I wanna apply the behaviour to a button

Comment: And why don't use a `RadioButton` and let it look like a normal `Button`? It's much easier to change appearance than enforcing a different behavior on controls.

Comment: @IsaacLem Is there a specific behavior you need that you have in a button that you can't get in radiobutton? RadioButton also has a Click event.

Answer (score 0):

a simplier way is to make only one style and use triggers

```
<Style
  TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="#C0C0C0"/>
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#404040"/>
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
  <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
  <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="23"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate
        TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Border
          x:Name="Border"
          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
          CornerRadius="2">
          <ContentPresenter
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#808080"/>
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#606060"/>
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

hope that helps

```
<Button
  Width="100"
  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
  VerticalAlignment="Center"
  Content="Click Me"/>
```

**EDIT**

better solution with a converter

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Orientation="Horizontal">
  <StackPanel.Resources>
    <wpfApplication2:MouseOverToBackgroundConverter x:Key="MouseOverToBackgroundConverter"
                                                    NormalBackground="LightGreen"
                                                    SelfMouseOverBackground="Red"
                                                    MouseOverBackground="Firebrick" />

    <Style x:Key="styleWithTrigger" TargetType="Rectangle">
      <Setter Property="Fill" Value="LightGreen" />
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </StackPanel.Resources>
  <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100"
              Margin="5" Style="{StaticResource styleWithTrigger}">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MouseOverToBackgroundConverter}">
        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="IsMouseOver" Mode="OneWay" />
        <Binding ElementName="theOtherRect" Path="IsMouseOver" Mode="OneWay" />
      </MultiBinding>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
  </Rectangle>
  <Rectangle x:Name="theOtherRect"
              Width="100" Height="100"
              Margin="5" Style="{StaticResource styleWithTrigger}" />
</StackPanel>
```

the converter

```
public class MouseOverToBackgroundConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
  public Brush NormalBackground { get; set; }
  public Brush SelfMouseOverBackground { get; set; }
  public Brush MouseOverBackground { get; set; }

  public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    if (values[0] is bool && values[1] is bool) {
      var selfIsMouseOver = (bool)values[0];
      var otherIsMouseOver = (bool)values[1];
      if (selfIsMouseOver) {
        return this.SelfMouseOverBackground;
      }
      return otherIsMouseOver ? this.MouseOverBackground : this.NormalBackground;
    }
    return this.NormalBackground;
  }

  public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    return targetTypes.Select(t => DependencyProperty.UnsetValue).ToArray();
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code can only change the color from `#C0C0C0` to `#808080` after being clicked right? But it cant be change back to `#C0C0C0` again right?

Comment: @IsaacLem he it's an example, try it out ( http://www.kaxaml.com ) and learn something about trigger ( http://wpftutorial.net/Triggers.html ) ...

Comment: Ok look, from the link you can see the green and the red box right? When `IsMouseOver`, the box will be filled with red. Now what I want is, when `IsMouseOver` on the right box, the left box will be filled with red instead!

Comment: @IsaacLem look at my last edit, simple example with rectangles and a comverter